# Is ArrayLists so slow that it is doomed to kill performance in Unity?

Tags: unity, performance

I was reading [Which Kind Of Array Or Collection Should I Use?](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use?)

The document states to use list for the most performance.

> "...They are the fastest array in unity. For this reason, built-in arrays are the best choice if you need the fastest performance possible from your code (for example, if you're targeting iPhone)...performs significantly faster than ArrayList."

I am inclined to use list besides performance issues as well because...

- [If you're using List you won't have to cast objects since it's generic and use a T[] backing storage (at least .net does this). ArrayList have to cast everything to object and cause boxing with value types.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/54354/what-is-better-on-iphone-arraylist-or-listt.html)
- [faster for value types as it avoids boxing., strongly typed elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815565/which-is-better-array-arraylist-or-listt-in-terms-of-performance-and-speed)

But it got me to wonder, since everyone seems to favor to make a degrading statement about ArrayLists, is ArrayLists *that* horrible? If so why does it even exist? Is it more of trace of supposedly deprecated codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `ArrayLists` are slow (relative). `ArrayLists` were part of the .NET framework before .NET 2.0 was released. .NET 2.0 brought us generics which are better for 'generic' collections. More specifically, `ArrayLists`' `.Add` method accepts objects causing boxing, whereas, a `List<T>` takes a predetermined type.. therefore, increasing performance.

For all practical purposes, the functionality of `ArrayList` in the current .NET Framework is for backwards compatibility with project using .NET Framework 1.0 / 1.1.

Comment: They are so slow and old that they are not supported anymore for newer platforms, so you won't find them if you try to compile your game to *Windows Phone* or *Windows Store Apps*.